# Jquery - How to find an element using class and attribute

Tags: jquery, class, find, attributes, element

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to find my element. Following i smy structure:

```
<div class="a" customattrib="2">
```

in order to find this element can I do something like :

```
$("div.a [customattrib='2']")
```

This does not seem to work, is there another way to do this?

Without the class I am able to get the value but I do not think this is efficient enough for my structure:

```
$("div [customattrib='2']")
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Remove the space:

```
$("div.a[customattrib='2']")
```

By putting in the space, you're making it into a descendant selector which finds all elements that match `[customattrib='2']` and are *inside* an element that matches `div.a`.