# How to make selector that find class and data-id=X

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<ul>
<li id="RadListBox1_i2" class="rlbItem ui-draggable">

    <div class="ui-draggable ui-state-default" data-shortid="1007">
    <em>ProductId: </em>
    <span>110-01-070-10</span>
    <br>
    <em>ShortID: </em>
    <span class="ShortID" data-shortid="1007">1007</span>
    <br>
    <em>Product Name: </em>
    <span>Clearly Retro Style Colour Name Necklace</span>
    <br>

    <em>
    </div>
    </span>
    </li>
    <li id="RadListBox1_i3" class="rlbItem ui-draggable">
    <li id="RadListBox1_i4" class="rlbItem ui-draggable">

</ul>
```

I need to build selector that find element that contains id=X and disable this item by `.draggable('disable');`

Some think like this:

find class y where `data-shortid=X` and make it

```
$("ul li").find(".ShortID").attr("data-shortid="+X+).draggable('disable');
```

Answer :

`$("span.ShortID[data-shortid="+ShortId+"]").parents("li:first").draggable("disable");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

Comment: I need to find element based on 1:Class And 2:data-attribute AND 3:make it draggable(disable)?Sow no it is no duplicate!!!

Comment: You didn't know how to select elements by attribute, and that's what the other question covers. Additionally selecting by class just means to combine both selectors. Look [how many selectors exist](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), we cannot have a question about every possible combination of those. We have to expect that people at least know the basics of CSS selectors.

Comment: But if it makes you feel better, this question could be closed as duplicate of [Jquery - How to find an element using class and attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2148523/218196).

Comment: Hhhhhh...yea you right(you got me with last link it is the same) i tried to combine all by my self but i get stuck.Sow i come here.Thx any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the li, not the span, so you need to find the parent:

```
$("span.ShortID[data-shortid=1007]").parents("li").draggable("disable");
```

Comment: This code working but when i replace 1007 to my var ShortID (i check that ShortID not null)   ` $("span.ShortID[data-shortid="+ShortId+"]").parents("li").draggable("disable");` it give me error` Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'`

Comment: What is the value of ShortId when you get that error? are you sure that it is draggable?

Comment: @Vova: The error is clear, isn't it? You are trying to disable the draggable behavior of an element that is not draggable.

Comment: I find the problem when i test with 1007 it takes first li that have draggable BUT when i use +ShortId+ it for some reasons take last parent of li sow i change a little bit code to this   $("span.ShortID[data-shortid=" + ShortId + "]").parents("li:first").draggable("disable"); and know it works

Comment: @Vova: If you have a nested list, then `.parents('li')` will select all `li` elements that are ancestors of the element. Some of them might not be draggable and hence you get the error. You probably want `.closest('li')` instead or even better `.closest('li.ui-draggable')`.

Comment: Yes exactly but when i put id by my self 1007(hardcode) it take the li.ui-draggable  but with var id it take the li that not draggble and it make no seance becase there no difference between (hard-coded 1007) and var id i check it .any it work now.thx

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$("ul li.ShortID[data-shortid="+X+"]").draggable('disable');
```

**EDITED:**

```
   var obj = $("ul li span.ShortID");
   var ids = obj.attr("data-shortid");
   if(ids == X) {
     obj.draggable('disable');
   }
```

Comment: It seems like good code but it doesn't work.I also tried  $("ul li span.ShortID[data-shortid=1005]").draggable('disable');

Comment: But this work $("#RadListBox1_i2").draggable('disable'); work buti need to check the id and then make it disable

Comment: @VovaPotapov what is you want to check. can you give some specification.

Comment: `ids` is a string. How is `ids..draggable('disable');` supposed to work (ignoring the syntax error)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ShortID[data-shortid=1007]")
```

Above code will return you the element with class="ShortID" and attribute data-shortid="1007"
When the element is picked, you can do anything you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([jQuery Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)):

```
$("ul li .ShortID[data-shortid='"+X+"']").draggable('disable');
```

Answer (score 0):

From [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$( ",someclass[data-id='yourid']" ).dosomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li").find(".ShortID").attr("data-shortid="+X+).draggable('disable');
```

Would find all elements that have is inside a ul li that has a class .ShortID.
To grab a element by an attribute and value. You could do

```
$("div[data-shortid=" + x );
```

*Beware that in your example you have to divs with the same ID.*

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Btw. Keep using find to nest deeper as in your example, this will help on performence.