# How to remove a parent div that contains certain keywords in a link's title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter, userscripts

I'm currently looking for a way to completely remove a parent DIV containing a couple of spans and then an `a[title="any-keywords-i-want-to-block"]`

The CSS userstyle I'm currently using is only removing the `a[title~="pony"]` and not the parent div.

Looks like this:

```
div >* a[title~="Pony"], div >* a[title~="brony"] {display:none !important;}
```

What I would like to do is to convert this into an user script for Tamper monkey that filters out a couple of words (case insensitive). I don't like in the link title. It should then remove the entire parent DIV (that also contains a couple of spans) if any of those keywords can be found inside the link title.

[This is the site in question](http://browse.deviantart.com), if you need to look at the site's source.

I'm trying to remove the entire thumbnail div if the link's title contains pony, brony, flutter shy and anything mlp related.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - How to find an element using class and attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148523/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-using-class-and-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't do this in CSS--CSS cascades downwards, you can't go up the tree.

In order to do this, you'll have to do it with Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('a[title~="pony"]').parent().hide();
```